# Mongo query and response 'GroupBy' implementation using Mongoose and/or underscore.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

We have a mongo collection `messages` that is in the following format...

```
/* 0 */
{
  "text" : "A message to John",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-01-29T23:50:10.488Z"),
  "to" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
    "name" : "John Smith"
  },
  "from" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
    "name" : "Martin Fowler"
  },
}
/* 1 */
{
  "text" : "Another message to John",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
  "to" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
    "name" : "John Smith"
  },
  "from" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
    "name" : "Martin fowler"
  },
}

/* 2 */
{
  "text" : "Just another message to Jerry",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
  "to" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e80eb5bf8800b0f5a8d"),
    "name" : "Jerry Jones"
  },
  "from" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
    "name" : "Martin Fowler"
  },
}
/* 2 */
{
  "text" : "Message to Martin Fowler",
  "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
  "to" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e80eb5bf8800b0f5a8d"),
    "name" : "Martin Fowler"
  },
  "from" : {
    "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
    "name" : "Jerry Jones"
  },
}
```

We need to display the data above in a conversation format where we group each of the conversations together. A conversation meaning that it can either be `to` or `from`.

An example of what we need this to data to look like is the following format:

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "id":"54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d",
         "name":"Jerry Jones",
         "messages":[  
            {
              "text" : "A message to John",
              "created" : ISODate("2015-01-29T23:50:10.488Z"),
              "to" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
                "name" : "John Smith"
              },
              "from" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                "name" : "Martin Fowler"
              },
            }
            {
              "text" : "Another message to John",
              "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
              "to" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
                "name" : "John Smith"
              },
              "from" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                "name" : "Martin fowler"
              },
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"54bf1e80eb5bf8800b0f5a8d",
         "name":"John Smith",
         "messages":[  
            {
              "text" : "Just another message to Jerry",
              "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
              "to" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e80eb5bf8800b0f5a8d"),
                "name" : "Jerry Jones"
              },
              "from" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                "name" : "Martin Fowler"
              },
            }
            {
              "text" : "Message to Martin Fowler",
              "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
              "to" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e80eb5bf8800b0f5a8d"),
                "name" : "Martin Fowler"
              },
              "from" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                "name" : "Jerry Jones"
              },
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**NOTE** This query is always made in the context of a `current user` which is why on each of the conversations, we have an `_id` and a `name` which represents the other user in the conversation. For the example above, the `current user` would be `Martin Fowler`

We have tried several different ways of accomplishing this, but keep running into issues. Id rather turn to the Mongo/Node community in order to see how it can be done correctly. We are using `mongoose` with Node if that helps at all...

The initial query implementation that we have currently is the following:

```
Message.find().or([{'from.id':req.user.id},{'to.id':req.user.id}]).exec(function(err,messages){

    //NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS HERE CORRECTLY
});
```

**NOTE** that the `req.user.id` is the id of the `current user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a slight modification of my previous solution to a similar kind of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725658/listing-the-last-message-of-each-conversation-involving-an-user-in-mongodb/26747130#26747130).

The documents in question have member names in inconsistent cases. `Martin Folwer` should be `Martin Fowler` throughout the app/database, and not `Martin fowler`. (Note the small `f`). You need to make this change to your documents.

- `$group` messages together, based on the `to` and `from` field.
  construct a group key - "message_between", with the value being a
  [**$concat**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) result of the values in `to` and `from` fields.
- Messages from `Martin Fowler` to `Jerry Jones` and `Jerry Jones` to
  `Martin Fowler` should be treated under a single group.To achieve
  that,  we make the result contain the name coming last
  alphabetically, first. So our key for all the Messages from `Martin
  Fowler` to  `Jerry Jones` and `Jerry Jones` to `Martin Fowler` would be
  `Martin Fowler and Jerry Jones`.

Code:

```
Model.aggregate(
//match all those records which involve the user.
{$match:{$or:[{"to.name":req.user.id},
              {"from.name":req.user.id}]}},
{$group:{"_id":{
    "message_between":{
        $cond:[
            {
                $gt:[
                {$substr:["$to.name",0,1]},
                {$substr:["$from.name",0,1]}]
            },
            {$concat:["$to.name"," and ","$from.name"]},
            {$concat:["$from.name"," and ","$to.name"]}
        ]
    },"name":{$cond:[{$eq:["$to.name",
                           req.user.id]},
                     "$from.name",
                     "$to.name"]}
    },"messages":{$push:"$$ROOT"}
    }
},
{$project:{"_id":0,"name":"$_id.name","messages":1}}
,function(err,resp){
   // handle response.
})
```

o/p:

```
{
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54d1d819b62f332e93fbb906"),
                        "text" : "Just another message to Jerry",
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
                        "to" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e80eb5bf8800b0f5a8d"),
                                "name" : "Jerry Jones"
                        },
                        "from" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                                "name" : "Martin Fowler"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54d1d819b62f332e93fbb907"),
                        "text" : "Message to Martin Fowler",
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
                        "to" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e80eb5bf8800b0f5a8d"),
                                "name" : "Martin Fowler"
                        },
                        "from" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                                "name" : "Jerry Jones"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Jerry Jones"
}
{
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54d1d819b62f332e93fbb904"),
                        "text" : "A message to John",
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-01-29T23:50:10.488Z"),
                        "to" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
                                "name" : "John Smith"
                        },
                        "from" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                                "name" : "Martin Fowler"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("54d1d819b62f332e93fbb905"),
                        "text" : "Another message to John",
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
                        "to" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
                                "name" : "John Smith"
                        },
                        "from" : {
                                "id" : ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                                "name" : "Martin Fowler"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "name" : "John Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a mongo request for you, but i'm not sure it's relevant...
I can generate almost exactly the same format as you need in one request:

```
db.messages.aggregate([{$match:{$or:[{"from.id":ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d")},{"to.id":ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d")}]}},{$group:{_id: ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"), messages:{$push: "$$ROOT"}}}]);
```

The probleme is, you still need to specify the id, i'm not sure it's what you need.

Using this I get the following result:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
    "messages": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("54d1b9f02cd45cae7e453633"),
            "text": "A message to John",
            "created": ISODate("2015-01-29T23:50:10.488Z"),
            "to": {
                "id": ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
                "name": "John Smith"
            },
            "from": {
                "id": ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                "name": "Martin Fowler"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("54d1ba052cd45cae7e453634"),
            "text": "Another message to John",
            "created": ISODate("2015-01-30T00:37:38.106Z"),
            "to": {
                "id": ObjectId("54bf1dc6c65b030c00faec0d"),
                "name": "John Smith"
            },
            "from": {
                "id": ObjectId("54bf1e1ceb5bf8800b0f5a8c"),
                "name": "Martin fowler"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not using mongoose so I can't help you with this part, but with "mongodb" module, this query can be used directly, so it should be possible with mongoose too.